# How do I fix deformities when printing on my Ender 3 V2?

Tags: creality-ender-3, print-quality, pla, stringing, mriscoc

Being a newbie in 3D printing, I have some trouble with my prints. After removing wiggle room from the X axis and the bed, there are deformities even on simple prints. The first layer turns out okay-ish but there seems to be some stringing that makes the print deviate consisently when there is a turn. How could I improve?
My setup:

```
Ender 3 V2 - stock printing bed, extruder/nozzles
Firmware: mriscoc
Auto bed leveling (BL touch) - Z offset -2.18mm
Slicer: Cura - 0.2mm layers, 20% infill
Material: PLA - 200C nozzle, 60C printing bed.
```

The Gcode of the XYZ cube:

```
;FLAVOR:Marlin
;Layer height: 0.2
;Generated with Cura_SteamEngine 5.3.0
M140 S50
M105
M190 S50
M104 S200
M105
M109 S200
M82 ;absolute extrusion mode
; Ender 3 Custom Start G-code
G92 E0 ; Reset Extruder
G28 ; Home all axes
M420 S1 ; Use mesh level stored
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ; Move Z Axis up little to prevent scratching of Heat Bed
```

Sample output (XYZ cube):

[image: X face]

[image: Y face]

[image: Z face]

[image: Side view]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: I identified the issue as a lack of tension in the X and Y timing belts. After tightening the belts, the prints are much smoother !

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question! Please accept the answer after 48 hours! Looking at the images I also suspected belt tension, it is quite clear from the top side view!